# Show sub-buttons of TActionToolBar when top level button is clicked

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I have a toolbar using TActionToolBar and TActionManager. A button has sub-buttons that are available clicking the small down arrow placed in the right of the button. All is managed by VCL and works fine.

I would like to show the sub-buttons when I click the top level button. Now, I need to click just the small arrow, but I would like that the entire button does the same.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a DropDown control that acts when an item is selected.  Other than that, just put code in the OnButtonClick method to simulate the down arrow being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the following working for my project.  I could not find a way to directly reference the button that is created on the ActionBar.  However the ActionComponent is set to the button that is created at runtime.

This of course had to be an Action itself to hook up to the main button on the Action Bar where the child items where attached.

```
procedure TReportPlugin.actMyDropdownExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActionButton: TCustomDropDownButton;
begin
  inherited;

  if (Sender is TAction) then
  begin

    if (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent is TCustomDropDownButton then
    begin
      ActionButton := (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent as TCustomDropDownButton;
      ActionButton.DropDownClick;
    end;

  end;
end;
```